# Grokking F# async vs. System.Threading.Task

Tags: f#, f#-giraffe

Let's consider I've function `loadCustomerProjection`:

```ml
let loadCustomerProjection id =
    use session = store.OpenSession()

    let result =
      session.Load<CustomerReadModel>(id)

    match result with
    | NotNull -> Some result
    | _ -> None
```

`session.Load` is synchronous and returns a `CustomerReadModel`

`session` also provides a `LoadAsync` method which I'm been using like this:

```ml
let loadCustomerProjection id =
    use session = store.OpenSession()

    let y = async {
      let! x =  session.LoadAsync<CustomerReadModel>(id) |> Async.AwaitTask
      return x
    }
    let x = y |> Async.RunSynchronously
    match x with
      | NotNull -> Some x
      | _ -> None
```

What I'm trying to understand:

Does the second version even make sense and does it add any value in terms of non blocking behavior as both have the same signature: `Guid -> CustomerReadModel option`?

Would it make more sense to have this signature `Guid -> Async<CustomerReadModel>` if `loadCustomerProjection` is called from with an Giraffe HttpHandler?

Or considering the Giraffe context, would be even better to have the signature `Guid -> Task<CustomerReadModel>`?

In my Giraffe handler what I want to do at least is to handle a `null` result via pattern matching as 404 - so at some point I need to have an `|> Async.AwaitTask` call anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this particular case there is no difference between your first and second version, except that you go through all the hoops in the second version to call the async function and then immediately wait for it. But the second version blocks exactly like the first one does.

As for the hot vs cold comments in the other answers; Because you wrapped the call to LoadAsync in an async computation expression, it stays cold (because async expression only executes when it is run). If on the other hand you would write

```
let y =
    session.LoadAsync<CustomerReadModel>(id)
    |> Async.AwaitTask
```

Then the LoadAsync would start executing immediately.

If you want to support async operations then it would indeed make sense make the entire function async:

```
let loadCustomerProjection id =
    async {
        use session = store.OpenSession()
  
        let! x =  session.LoadAsync<CustomerReadModel>(id) |> Async.AwaitTask

        match x with
        | NotNull -> return Some x
        | _ -> return None
    }
```

Whether you would use Task or Async is up to you. Personally I prefer Async because it's native to F#. But in your case you might want to stick with [Giraffe's decision to stick with Task](https://github.com/giraffe-fsharp/Giraffe/blob/master/DOCUMENTATION.md#tasks) to avoid conversions.

Answer (score 0):

Since the main difference between a Task and an Async is that when you have a Task it is always Hot whereas the Async is Cold (until you decide to run it) it makes sense to work with Async in your backend code and then when it is time for Giraffe to use it, convert it into a Task or run it.

In your case you are just doing one thing. I imagine it is more useful to go full async if you have multiple async steps that you want to compose in some way.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/tutorials/asynchronous-and-concurrent-programming/async#combine-asynchronous-computations for example.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the other answer the main difference between Task and Async is that Tasks are started immediately whereas Asyncs must be started explicitly.

In the simple example above it wouldn't make much difference in returning the 'T, Async<'T>, or Task<'T>. My preference would probably be Task<'T> as that is what you are receiving in the function and it makes sense to continue propagating the Task<_> until the final point of use.

Note that when you are using Giraffe you should have access to [TaskBuilder.fs](https://github.com/rspeele/TaskBuilder.fs) which gives you a `task { }` computation expression in the `FSharp.Control.Tasks.V2` module.